# Tetrahedron version of Pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, platonic-solids

Consider a tetrahedron with an equilateral base and two of the other three faces being right triangles with their right angle points meeting.  This leaves the last face to be some isosceles triangle.  Let the area of the base equal $A$, the area of one of the right triangular faces equal $B$, and the area of the isosceles face equal $C$.

Show a simple proof that $A^2+B^2=C^2$

Comment: What do you mean by "final face"? There are still two other faces, which one are you referring to?

Comment: Lazy lee ? Base face... 1.  Right triangle face... 2 and 3.  One face remaining is 4.

Comment: No no. He's all good. I edited my question after his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ be a length-side of the base and let $h$ be an altitude to the base of the pyramid.

Thus, we have
$$\frac{3a^4}{16}+\frac{a^2h^2}{4}=\frac{a^2\left(h^2+\frac{3a^2}{4}\right)}{4},$$
which is $$A^2+B^2=C^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the base $A$ have sides $a$, the tetrahedron have height $b$, and the remaining side lengths be $c$.

Using Heron's Formula we have $$A^2 = \frac{3a}{2}(\frac{3a}{2}-a)^3 = \frac{3a^4}{16} $$
$$C^2 = \frac{2c+a}{2}(\frac{2c+a}{2}-a)(\frac{2c+a}{2}-c)^2=\frac{4a^2c^2-a^4}{16} $$
$$ B^2 =\frac{a+b+c}{2}(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-a)(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-b)(\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c)=\frac{-a^4+2a^2(b^2+c^2)-(b^2-c^2)^2}{16}$$
As $a,b,c$ are legs of a right triangle with $c$ the hypotenuse we have $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $b^2=c^2-a^2$. Then substituting in $B^2$ we have $$B^2 = \frac{-a^4+2a^2(b^2+c^2)-(b^2-c^2)^2}{16} = \frac{-a^4+2a^2(c^2-a^2+c^2)-(b^2-(a^2+b^2))^2}{16}=\frac{4a^2c^2-4a^4}{16}$$
Finally we have $$A^2+B^2 =\frac{3a^4}{16}+\frac{4a^2c^2-4a^4}{16}=\frac{4a^2c^2-a^4}{16}=C^2 $$